# File System group policy option has disappeared for our default domain policy

Tags: windows, group-policy

We have a separate policy for Windows 10 Only accounts and that one shows the File System as it should (2nd picture). Any idea how this happens?

I tried "regsvr32 wsecedit.dll" in CMD but it says it's not found (picture 3)

I've also tried downloading the Microsoft ADMX/ADML files and replacing them in our sysvol but that didn't work either.

[image: Default Domain Policy]

[image: Windows 10 Only PC policy]

[image: Result from cmd]

Comment: "I tried running a cmd on wsecedit.dll to restore it but it says it's not found." makes no sense to me. Would you mind clarifying this?

Comment: Sorry, edited my submission

Comment: regsvr32 wsecedit.dll   ......  Did you run as Admin and did you navigate to the folder where wsecedit.dll is located to run regsver33 ?

Comment: Yessir. I added a picture of the run. As admin in C:\windows\system32

Comment: Can you run an Operating System Repair from the installation media for the domain machine? I am not sure if that will fix the issue.

Comment: What you are trying to do with that DLL is only for COM (which this DLL is not.. thus the error).  Follow @John advice and report back please.  This is not a typical problem but you have LOTS AND LOTS of windows experts here to help solve it.

Comment: Thanks! Silly question.. since our server is the main domain controller is the method of running "operating system repair" going to return the os to defaults? Is this the only option?